Prove that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2}{e^{(2n+1)U} - 1} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sinh{(nU)}}$
How do I show that from the left hand side of the identity follows the right hand side
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2}{e^{(2n+1)U} - 1} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sinh{(nU)}}\; .
\end{align}
I tried using $\sinh x = \frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{2}$, but I still can't see the next course of action.
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sinh{(nU)}} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{e^{nU} - e^{-nU}} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2e^{nU}}{e^{2nU} - 1} = ...$$ Here I tried two things, the first was
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2e^{nU}}{e^{2nU} - 1} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2e^{(n+1)U}}{e^{2(n+1)U} - 1} = ...$$
and second was
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2e^{nU}}{e^{2nU} - 1} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{e^{nU}-1} +\frac{1}{e^{nU}+1} =...$$

Let us define the series
$$S[k(n)]\equiv\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{2}{e^{k(n)U}-1}$$
Notice it doesn't start at $n=0$ like in yours or else it'd diverge for $k=n$ and $k=2n$.
We can split the $k=n$ into two odd and even indexes summations and then isolate yours in terms of the others:
$$\begin{aligned}S[n]=S[2n]+S[2n-1]&\implies S[2n-1]=S[n]-S[2n]\\
&\implies\ \sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{2}{e^{(2n-1)U}-1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{2}{e^{nU}-1}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{2}{e^{2nU}-1}\\
&\implies\color{blue}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{2}{e^{(2n+1)U}-1}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{2}{e^{nU}-1}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{2}{e^{2nU}-1}\\
&\hspace{4.4cm}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{2e^{nU}}{e^{2nU}-1}\\
&\hspace{4.4cm}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{2}{e^{nU}-e^{-nU}}\\
&\hspace{4.55cm}\color{blue}{=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{\sinh(nU)}}\end{aligned}$$

N is both the argument of your function and the index of summation. That doesn't make sense

preferrably yes

Thanks man! When you see a solution it looks soooo easy

\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{2}{{{\rm e}^{(2n + 1)U}  - 1}}}&  = 2\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {{\rm e}^{ - (2n + 1)U} \sum\limits_{m = 0}^\infty  {{\rm e}^{ - (2n + 1)mU} } } 
\\ & 
 = 2\sum\limits_{m = 0}^\infty  {\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {{\rm e}^{ - (2n + 1)U} {\rm e}^{ - (2n + 1)mU} } } 
\\ & 
 = 2\sum\limits_{m = 0}^\infty  {{\rm e}^{ - (m + 1)U} \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {{\rm e}^{ - n(2m + 2)U} } } \\ &  = 2\sum\limits_{m = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{{\rm e}^{ - (m + 1)U} }}{{1 - {\rm e}^{ - (2m + 2)U} }}} 
\\ & 
 = \sum\limits_{m = 0}^\infty  {\frac{2}{{{\rm e}^{(m + 1)U}  - {\rm e}^{ - (m + 1)U} }}}\\ &  = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{2}{{{\rm e}^{nU}  - {\rm e}^{ - nU} }}} 
\\ & = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{\sinh (nU)}}} 
\end{align*}

Why can we change order of summation?

The sums converge absolutely (the terms are positive and the sums converge) for all $U>0$.
